# Unknown database function 'DATE_FORMAT' in OracleDb

Tags: mysql, oracle, datetime, group-by, to-char

Below is how my `BUS_DATA` table looks like

[image]

Below is my query where for a single day it picks the maximum `currentSpeed` and returns that row for the busId selected

> SELECT busId, busName, passengersNo, speedLimit, dataDateTime, DATE_FORMAT(dataDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') dataDate , max(currentSpeed) currentSpeed from BUS_DATA where busId = '4-3323309834' GROUP BY busId, dataDate

Below is how this query looks like when it runs

[image]

This was all working well when i was using `MySQL` until when i migrated to `Oracle RDBMS` where i am getting below errors

```
Unknown database function 'DATE_FORMAT'

Column 'busName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Column 'passengersNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Column 'speedLimit' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Column 'speedLimit' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

I have tried to modify `DATE_FORMAT` to  to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and making the query to look like below but its still showing errors how can i convert the above query to Oracle RDBMS

```
SELECT busId, busName, passengersNo, speedLimit, dataDateTime, to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') dataDate ,
  max(currentSpeed) currentSpeed from BUS_DATA where busId = '4-3323309834' GROUP BY busId, dataDate
```

`dataDateTime` field in my table is Timestamp

Comment: I suggest you read up on oracle date functions and fix the MySQL non standard implementation of group by(

Comment: If it is really Oracle RDBMS - your referred to "Oracle MySQL" as distinct from "MySQL" which is confusing as they are the same thing - then what is generating those error messages, as they aren't ORA- errors? What errors do you get after changing to `to_char()`? Just the 'Column x is invalid...' ones? And please post your data and resulsts as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @AlexPoole i have edited the question it should be Oracle RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` you either need to include the column in the `GROUP BY` clause or you need to use an aggregation function and you cannot use an alias declared in the `SELECT` clause in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT busId,
       to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dataDate,
       max(currentSpeed) AS currentSpeed
from   BUS_DATA
where  busId = '4-3323309834'
GROUP BY
       busId,
       to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you want to add more columns then:

```sql
SELECT busId,
       busName,
       passengersNo,
       speedLimit,
       dataDateTime,
       to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dataDate ,
       max(currentSpeed) AS currentSpeed
from   BUS_DATA
where  busId = '4-3323309834'
GROUP BY
       busId,
       busName,
       passengersNo,
       speedLimit,
       dataDateTime
```

or:

```sql
SELECT busId,
       MAX(busName) AS busName,
       MAX(passengersNo) AS passengerNo,
       MAX(speedLimit) AS speedLimit,
       MAX(dataDateTime) AS dateDateTime,
       to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dataDate ,
       max(currentSpeed) AS currentSpeed
from   BUS_DATA
where  busId = '4-3323309834'
GROUP BY
       busId,
       to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or don't use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY busId, to_char(dataDateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           ORDER BY currentSpeed DESC
         ) AS rn
  from   BUS_DATA t
  where  busId = '4-3323309834'
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: @MTO what if i want to display the other columns

Comment: @MTO thank you for the explanation all of them are working perfectly